# Push Notification Not Works Properly

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I have created on Chatting Application in Android.

In that I have problem occurs in Push Notification.

Problem is:

- When User A Send Message to User X, so X gets the Push.
- After that User B Send Message to User X, so X gets second the Push.

Then User X clicks on Push of User A Chat Screen not opens, but clicks on Push of User B Chat Screen opens.

How to resolve this.

```
    PendingIntent contentIntent;
    UserSessionManager userSession = new UserSessionManager(context);
    if (type.equals("2"))
    {
        if (userSession.getUserSession() != null = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class)
                            .putExtra("to_id", from_id)
                            .putExtra("username", username)
                            .putExtra("to_avt", to_avt)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
        else
        {
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context,
                    SplashActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }

    }

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(from_id), mBuilder.build());
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: try to add this code add flags
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("to_id", from_id)
                        .putExtra("username", username)
                        .putExtra("to_avt", to_avt)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This code overwrites the `PendingIntent` every time. So you will only ever have one `PendingIntent` (containing the most recent set of "extras").

What you need is to ensure that for each different chat session, you generate a different `PendingIntent`. To make the `PendingIntent` unique, you can either generate a unique "Intent action" or use a unique `requestCode` parameter.

if we assume that `from_id` is a unique integer for each session, you could use that as the `requestCode`, like this:

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                from_id, // unique requestCode
                new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("to_id", from_id)
                        .putExtra("username", username)
                        .putExtra("to_avt", to_avt)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

or if `username` is a unique string, you could use that as the "Intent action" like this:

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class)
                        .setAction(username) // Unique ACTION
                        .putExtra("to_id", from_id)
                        .putExtra("username", username)
                        .putExtra("to_avt", to_avt)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

either of these solutions will ensure that you generate a separate `PendingIntent` for each session.