# How to register multiple PendingIntents for same destination?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I want to create multiple `PendingIntents` for same destination in my App. In my case, destination is `BroadcastReceiver` class, which will fire notification. Entire notification is part of the content of `PendingIntent`.

But what I've found out is **only last** registered `PendingIntent` is sent to `onReceive` of `BroadcastReceiver`. Since I cant check anything about `PendingIntent` because its write-only interface, but I can confirm that at least 5 `PendingIntents` were created with different notification content. But only one made it to `BroadcastReceiver` and it was the last one. That means each new `PendingIntent` will rewrite data of the previous one.

Is there any way how to register 10 or more `PendingIntents` with same destination but different body?

Example of creating `PendingIntent` for notification:

```
data class PendingNotification(val objectUID: Long, val pInt: PendingIntent)
    var pendingIntentList = mutableListOf<PendingNotification>()
    fun createAlarmPendingIntent(a: Activity, nb: NotificationCompat.Builder?, notId: Int,
                                        id: Long): PendingIntent{
        val nInt = Intent(a, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        nInt.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, notId)
        nInt.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION, nb?.build())

        val pInt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            a,
            0,
            nInt,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        App.log("PendingId - createPendingInt: $notId")
        //save pending intent for future cancelation by id 
        pendingIntentList.add(PendingNotification(id, pInt))
        return pInt
    }

private fun createAlarm(){
        val pInt = app.createAlarmPendingIntent(a, nb, notId, id)
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.time = alarmTime
        app.aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pInt)
    }
```

Comment: Can you try reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168484/pendingintent-works-correctly-for-the-first-notification-but-incorrectly-for-the#comment3283736_3168653. My short research lead me to conclusion that you need to make each PendingIntent unique and set a proper flag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that each `PendingIntent` is unique. There are several ways to do this: use different `requestCode`s, use different `Intent` ACTIONs, etc. See [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307701/769265) for more details.